# Looking for alternative to javascript lookbehind for phone number regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern to check for input phone number. Regex pattern is:

```php
(@"((?:\(?[2-9](?(?=1)1[02-9]|(?(?=0)0[1-9]|\d{2}))\)?\D{0,3})(?:\(?[2-9](?(?=1)1[02-9]|\d{2})\)?\D{0,3})\d{4})"
```

This works fine for Server side validation and fails for client-side. I get the `Invalid group error`.

I am fairly new to regex and by digging around I found out that it is because JS doesn't support lookbehind.

I tried to apply the - inversing the string technique but the pattern is too complicated.
Could someone please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your conditional constructs need to be replaced with a non-capturing group that contains a negative lookahead at the start. In general, it looks like

```js
(?(?=0)01|\d{2}) = (?:(?=0)01|(?!0)\d{2})
```

That is, you convert a conditional group into a non-capturing group, and add restrictions to each alternative in the group. `(?:(?=0)01|(?!0)\d{2})` matches `01` if the next char is `0`, else, if the next char is not `0`, match any two digits (but not if they start with `0` of course).

So, in your concrete case, change

- `(?(?=1)1[02-9]|(?(?=0)0[1-9]|\d{2}))` -> `(?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?:(?=0)0[1-9]|(?!0)\d{2}))`
- `(?(?=1)1[02-9]|\d{2})` -> `(?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?!1)\d{2})`

The exact JavaScript equivalent for the PCRE pattern is

```cs
((?:\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?:(?=0)0[1-9]|(?!0)\d{2}))\)?\D{0,3})(?:\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?!1)\d{2})\)?\D{0,3})\d{4})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Np4onW/3).

However, some of the groupings are redundant, so you may shorten it to

```js
\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?:(?=0)0[1-9]|(?!0)\d{2}))\)?\D{0,3}\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?!1)\d{2})\)?\D{0,3}\d{4}
```

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor. Worked like a charm. And you explained it so well.